# In Julia is it worth type-narrowing a dictionary returned by `JSON.parsefile`

Tags: json, julia

I’m writing Julia code whose inputs are json files, that performs analysis in (the field of mathematical finance) and writes results as json. The code is a port from R in the hope of performance improvement.

I parse the input files using `JSON.parsefile`. This returns a Dict in which I observe that all vectors are of type `Array{Any,1}`. As it happens, I know that the input file will never contain vectors of mixed type, such as some `String`s and some `Number`s.
So I wrote the following code, which seems to work well and is “safe” in the sense that if the calls to `convert` fail then a vector continues to have type `Array{Any,1}`.

```
function typenarrow!(d::Dict)
    for k in keys(d)
        if d[k] isa Array{Any,1}
            d[k] = typenarrow(d[k])
        elseif d[k] isa Dict
            typenarrow!(d[k])
        end
    end
end

function typenarrow(v::Array{Any,1})
    for T in [String,Int64,Float64,Bool,Vector{Float64}]
        try
            return(convert(Vector{T},v))
        catch; end        
    end
    return(v)
end
```

My question is: Is this worth doing? Can I expect code that processes the contents of the `Dict` to execute faster if I do this type narrowing? I think the answer is yes in that the [Julia performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#Annotate-values-taken-from-untyped-locations-1) recommend to “Annotate values taken from untyped locations” and this approach ensures there are no “untyped locations”.

Comment: Not an answer, but there is [JSON2.jl](https://github.com/quinnj/JSON2.jl) which returns `NamedTuple` by default. If you know the fields and types of the JSON you can even set the type parameters of the `NamedTuple` to make the parsing extremely fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two levels of the answer to this question:

**Level 1**

Yes, it will help the performance of the code. See for instance the following benchmark:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = Any[1 for i in 1:10^6];

julia> y = [1 for i in 1:10^6];

julia> @btime sum($x)
  26.507 ms (477759 allocations: 7.29 MiB)
1000000

julia> @btime sum($y)
  226.184 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1000000
```

You can write your `typenarrow` function using a bit simpler approach like this:

```
typenarrow(x) = [v for v in x]
```

as using the comprehension will produce a vector of concrete type (assuming your source vector is homogeneous)

**Level 2**

This is not fully optimal. The problem that is still left is that you have a `Dict` that is a container with abstract type parameter (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-containers-with-abstract-type-parameters-1). Therefore in order for the computations to be fast you have to use a barrier function (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#kernel-functions-1) or use type annotation for variables you introduce (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Type-Declarations-1).

In the ideal world your `Dict` would have keys and values of homogeneous types and all would be maximally fast then, but if I understand your code correctly values in your case are not homogeneous.

**EDIT**

In order to solve the Level 2 isuue you can convert `Dict` into `NamedTuple` like this (this is a minimal example assuming that `Dict`s only nest in `Dict`s directly, but it should be easy enough to extend if you want more flexibility).

First, the function performing the conversion looks like:

```
function typenarrow!(d::Dict)
    for k in keys(d)
        if d[k] isa Array{Any,1}
            d[k] = [v for v in d[k]]
        elseif d[k] isa Dict
            d[k] = typenarrow!(d[k])
        end
    end
    NamedTuple{Tuple(Symbol.(keys(d)))}(values(d))
end
```

Now a MWE of its use:

```
julia> using JSON

julia> x = """
       {
         "name": "John",
         "age": 27,
         "values": {
           "v1": [1,2,3],
           "v2": [1.5,2.5,3.5]
         },
         "v3": [1,2,3]
       }
       """;

julia> j1 = JSON.parse(x)
Dict{String,Any} with 4 entries:
  "name"   => "John"
  "values" => Dict{String,Any}("v2"=>Any[1.5, 2.5, 3.5],"v1"=>Any[1, 2, 3])
  "age"    => 27
  "v3"     => Any[1, 2, 3]

julia> j2 = typenarrow!(j1)
(name = "John", values = (v2 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5], v1 = [1, 2, 3]), age = 27, v3 = [1, 2, 3])

julia> dump(j2)
NamedTuple{(:name, :values, :age, :v3),Tuple{String,NamedTuple{(:v2, :v1),Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Int64,1}}},Int64,Array{Int64,1}}}
  name: String "John"
  values: NamedTuple{(:v2, :v1),Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Int64,1}}}
    v2: Array{Float64}((3,)) [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
    v1: Array{Int64}((3,)) [1, 2, 3]
  age: Int64 27
  v3: Array{Int64}((3,)) [1, 2, 3]
```

The beauty of this approach is that Julia will know all types in `j2`, so if you pass `j2` to any function as a parameter all calculations inside this function will be fast.

The downside of this approach is that a function taking `j2` has to be pre-compiled, which might be problematic if `j2` structure is huge (as then the structure of resulting `NamedTuple` is complex) and the amount of work your function does is relatively small. But for small JSON-s (small in the sense of structure, as vectors held in them can be large - their size does not add to the complexity) this approach has proven to be efficient in several applications I have developed.

Comment: I have added an explanation how you can achieve a full type stability in simple cases.